# How to enable logging for google-cloud-cpp sdk

Tags: google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-cpp

I'm using google-cloud-cpp SDK from here: https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-cpp. However, I can't seem to figure out how to enable logging for the client library and find out where the log file goes. I'm interested in seeing all the HTTP requests being made to the endpoint. Appreciate any help and/or examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set two environment variables:

- `GOOGLE_CLOUD_CPP_ENABLE_CLOG=yes` will redirect the logs to `std::clog`, the library does not create a log backend otherwise.
- `CLOUD_STORAGE_TRACING=http,raw-client` otherwise logging is not even turned on.

You can find more information about environment variables for the SDK in the `API Notes` section of: https://googleapis.dev/cpp/google-cloud-storage/latest/index.html

Comment: If this helped you @TusharJagtap, please consider marking this answer as accepted for better visibility in the forum.

Comment: For the v2.10.0 SDK, use `CLOUD_STORAGE_ENABLE_TRACING=raw-client,http` instead of `GOOGLE_CLOUD_CPP_STORAGE_TRACING`. I am not sure when that change occurred.